# CreateCompatibleBitmap for the WP7 emulator returns Full Black Image

Tags: c#

I want to take screen shot for the WP7 emulator window.

When I use CreateCompatibleBitmap it returns full black image.

When using the same code with any other window it works fine.

Any ideas?!?

Comment: What is WP7? Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1):

Hey Now Mohammad Abdelaziz,

To take a screen shot of the WP7 Emulator we could use:

Snipping tool ( http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool )

Snagit a third party tool

Thanks,
Catto